# Template iterators, dereferencing, and typedef in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, iterator, dereference, quadtree

I'm getting strange results from a program I'm working on and can't figure out where the error is or why I'm getting it. I'm working on a templated quadtree class that uses a templated iterator. Even though my function seems to work correctly, it does not return the value it found.

This is my basic Quadtree class:

```
template <class number_type, class label_type>
class QuadTree {
public:
    // CONSTRUCTORS
    QuadTree() : size_(0), root_(NULL) {}

    // ACCESSORS
    unsigned int size() const { return size_; }

    typedef DepthIterator<number_type, label_type> iterator;

    iterator begin() const {
        return root_;
    }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(NULL); }

    // This is the function not returning the expected value 
    iterator find(number_type x, number_type y, Node<number_type, label_type>* parent = NULL) {
        if (parent == NULL) {
            // start at the root, if equal return, otherwise call recursively
            if (root_->pt.x == x && root_->pt.y == y) { return iterator(root_); }
            else {
                return find(x, y, root_);
            }
        }
        else {
            int quadrant;
            // find the quadrant of the point
            if (x < parent->pt.x && y < parent->pt.y) {
                quadrant = 0;
            }
            else if (x > parent->pt.x && y < parent->pt.y) {
                quadrant = 1;
            }
            else if (x < parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
                quadrant = 2;
            }
            else if (x > parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
                quadrant = 3;
            }
            // see if the quadrant is a branch or a leaf
            if (parent->children[quadrant] == NULL) {
                // child is a leaf and it matches the search
                if (x == parent->pt.x && y == parent->pt.y) { return iterator(parent); }
                // child is a leaf, but it does not match the search
                else { return iterator(NULL); }
            }
            else {
                // child is a branch, check if it's equal and return if it is, if not, continue on
                if (x == parent->pt.x && y == parent->pt.y) { return iterator(parent); }
                else { find(x, y, parent->children[quadrant]); }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    unsigned int size_;
    Node<number_type, label_type>* root_;
};
```

It seems that my find function finds the correct node on my quadtree, as I can use std::cout to print out the parent before it returns it for the correct value. However

```
return iterator(parent);
```

gives me either a NULL value or the point (9,0), which isn't in my quadtree.

Here is my DepthIterator class:

```
template <class number_type, class label_type>
class DepthIterator {
public:
    // CONSTRUCTOR / COPY / ASSIGN / DECONSTRUCTOR
    DepthIterator() : ptr_(NULL) {}
    DepthIterator(Node<number_type, label_type>* n) : ptr_(n) {}
    DepthIterator(const DepthIterator& old) : ptr_(old.ptr_) {}
    ~DepthIterator() {}

    // OPERATORS
    DepthIterator& operator=(const DepthIterator& old) { ptr_ = old.ptr_; return *this; }
    const Point<number_type>& operator*() const { return ptr_->pt; }
    bool operator== (const DepthIterator& rgt) { return ptr_ == rgt.ptr_; }
    bool operator!= (const DepthIterator& rgt) { return ptr_ != rgt.ptr_; }

    // ACCESSORS
    label_type getLabel() const { return ptr_->label; }


private:
    Node<number_type, label_type>* ptr_;
};
```

Perhaps my copy or dereference bits are the problem? I'm leaning towards dereference because my find function does work before that operation is used, but not after.

Here is my Node class:

```
template <class number_type, class label_type>
class Node {
public:
    Node() {}
    Node(Point<number_type> p, label_type l) : pt(p), label(l) { parent = NULL; }

    Node& operator=(const Node& old) { pt = old.pt; label = old.label; parent = *old; return *this; }

    Point<number_type> pt;
    label_type label;
    Node<number_type, label_type>* children[4];
    Node<number_type, label_type>* parent;
};
```

My main function would contain something like this:

```
QuadTree<int, char>::iterator itr = test.find(20,10);
// the point (20,10) does exist in the quadtree
assert (itr != test.end());
assert (itr.getLabel() == 'A');
// both of these tests pass

const Point<int> &pt = *itr;
assert (pt.x == 20);
assert (pt.y == 10);
// both of these tests pass

QuadTree<int,char>::iterator itr = test.find(4,7);
// the point (4,7) does exist in the quadtree
assert (itr != test.end());
// this test fails however ^
assert (itr.getLabel() == 'B');
```

The first test works, but the second doesn't. I'm not sure if this is because the first test is the root node, and the second test is not, or if it's because I dereference in the middle, or some other reason entirely. I'm somewhat new to C++ and really struggling to implement this. Can anyone explain why my find function isn't working?

Comment: You should probably minimize the code to only include code that produces the error / strange behaviour.

Comment: What happens if either X or Y equals root_->pt.x or root_->pt.y

Comment: @rozina I trimmed it down as much as possible. Part of it is that I'm not sure where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 iterator find(number_type x, number_type y, Node<number_type, label_type>* parent = NULL) {
    if (parent == NULL) {
        // start at the root, if equal return, otherwise call recursively
        if (root_->pt.x == x && root_->pt.y == y) { return iterator(root_); }
        else {
            return find(x, y, root_);
        }
    }
    else {
        int quadrant;
        // find the quadrant of the point
        if (x < parent->pt.x && y < parent->pt.y) {
            quadrant = 0;
        }
        else if (x > parent->pt.x && y < parent->pt.y) {
            quadrant = 1;
        }
        else if (x < parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
            quadrant = 2;
        }
        else if (x > parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
            quadrant = 3;
        }
        // see if the quadrant is a branch or a leaf
        if (parent->children[quadrant] == NULL) {
            // child is a leaf and it matches the search
            if (x == parent->pt.x && y == parent->pt.y) { return iterator(parent); }
            // child is a leaf, but it does not match the search
            else { return iterator(NULL); }
        }
        else {
            // child is a branch, check if it's equal and return if it is, if not, continue on
            if (x == parent->pt.x && y == parent->pt.y) { return iterator(parent); }
            else { find(x, y, parent->children[quadrant]); }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the undefined behaviour if x == parent->pt.x or y == parent->pt.y as quadrant will be undefined, because none of the if conditions evaluates to true. In this case `parent->children[quadrant] == NULL` behaves like schrodinger's cat, it might be true, it might be false.

A possile fix could be:

```
if (x <= parent->pt.x && y <= parent->pt.y) {
        quadrant = 0;
    }
    else if (x > parent->pt.x && y <= parent->pt.y) {
        quadrant = 1;
    }
    else if (x <= parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
        quadrant = 2;
    }
    else if (x > parent->pt.x && y > parent->pt.y) {
        quadrant = 3;
    }
```

Comment: I understand that my quadrant could be undefined, and fixed it as you suggested, but it didn't seem to fix my problem. The function finds the correct node, it just doesn't seem to return it correctly.

Comment: I see...my proposed solution should only fix the problem, if it correlates to the creation of the quadtree, right? Did you verify that too? As I understand you currently, you are debugging your code and it traverses correctly through the quadrants, until you reach the correct node, but the return value does not equal the value it should return inside the function?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It traverses fine to any of my test cases but the return value is not what it should be. I wrote a test function that I called inside of find and passed iterator(parent) and it received the correct value, so for some reason it is only failing to return the correct value within find.